# How To Accsess .exe File from C#

Tags: c#

I have a  .exe file for working reader card  but I must  to call from code this exe file gor working  How can I do it in C#?

Comment: `Process.Start()` if you want to just run it, if you want to do more you need to describe exactly what ...

Comment: Actually fisrt of all I have tried  installation packages for reader card and than I downloaded api dll but I cant add reference this dll after all ı find a usedllcmd for readers card for using this usedllcmd.exe I call in code But I dont know hot to call .exe file in c#

Answer (score 3):

you can  execute execute your process like this

```
Process p = new Process();
p.StartInfo.FileName = "file.exe";
p.Start();
```

or simply :

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("file.exe");
```

Comment: Thank Hmm I want to write  to console screen what  it is read ü For example reader card read 12345 I want to print console screen this number How can ı do it?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.standardoutput(v=vs.110).aspx